# Listen events caused by powerful buttons

Tags: javascript, validation, orbeon

I would like to be able to listen events caused by powerful buttons by using JavaScript. Basically I want to know if save is successful or failed. I can't find any documentation how to listen state of those events.

I could just add my own click listener to save button and try to find state of save from DOM, but there must be better way to do it...

References:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orbeon/i8R7_5uXI0I
- http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-javascript-integration

Answer (score 0):

There is no great answer for this right now. There is an [RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1611) for a JavaScript API which would include information such as knowing about a successful save.

In the meanwhile you could modify the `save-final` process to run JavaScript. With Orbeon Forms 4.6:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-final.*.*">
    require-uploads
    then validate-all
    then save
    then navigate(uri = "javascript:alert()")
    then success-message("save-success")
    recover error-message("database-error")
</property>
```

Instead of `alert()`, you would place a call to your callback function.